# Display a particular clicked newsAPI article on separat page

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, api, express

I'm making a news website and till now i've manage to display all the articles on single page using news API in nodeJs . it is working quite well so far but I'm looking to display the clikced article on a different page . I've managed to route it to different page but that page is always coming out blank as I couldn't figure out to fetch the clicked article contents to that page.
Can someone help me to achieve that .
I'm using express js and axios for fetching api .

I want to display result in art.ejs in same folder
This is my

> public/views/news.ejs

```
    <div class="news">
   
         <% if(articles != null) { %>
        <% articles.forEach(function(article, index) { %>
            <a  href="/art"class="news__card" id="newsCard">

                <img src="<%- article.urlToImage %>" >
                <h2><%- article.title %></h2>
                <p><%- article.content %></p>
            </a>
        <% }) %>
        <% } else { %>
            No posts found.
        <% } %>

              </div>
```

[THIS IS MY PROJECT STRUCTURE -->>](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ozUtY.png)

```
       const express = require('express')
       const newsRouter = express.Router()
       const axios = require('axios')






       newsRouter.get('/', async(req, res) => {
       try {
           const newsAPI = await axios.get(`https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=de&category=business&apiKey=48833d0497114efba2dddc237fd41fc3`)
           res.render('news', { articles : newsAPI.data.articles })
          } catch (err) {
           if(err.response) {
            res.render('news', { articles : null })
            console.log(err.response.data)
            console.log(err.response.status)
            console.log(err.response.headers)
         } else if(err.requiest) {
            res.render('news', { articles : null })
            console.log(err.requiest)
         } else {
            res.render('news', { articles : null })
            console.error('Error', err.message)
         }
      } 
     })

      newsRouter.get('/art',async(req ,res)=>{
       try{
          const newsAPI = await axios.get(`https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?`enter code here`country=de&category=business&apiKey=48833d0497114efba2dddc237fd41fc3`)

          console.log('Request for article recieved');
          res.render('art', { articles : newsAPI.data.articles });
        }
        catch (err) {
           if(err.response) {
             res.render('art', { articles : null })
             console.log(err.response.data)
             console.log(err.response.status)
             console.log(err.response.headers)
           } else if(err.requiest) {
             res.render('art', { articles : null })
             console.log(err.requiest)
           } else {
             res.render('art', { articles : null })
             console.error('Error', err.message)
           }
        } 



      })
```

Answer (score 0):

You can look for in you api docs fro getting single artical from the database ,
The most common way in which the api work is , they provide you a id for each item in this case artical you case that to and add that to the ejs template like this

```
<a href="<%= the url for that artical %>" >Artical</a>
```

You can search  in your api docs for getting single artical with id or something else which they have used to separate articals. Its not hard you can do it.

Comment: They don't have that in their docs and NewsAPI doesn't provide unique ID in their JSON OBEJCT which makes it even more hard to achieve what I want

Comment: If they are only provding array of data only you can use js on the ejs file , make a hidden div with the UI for only one article as you want and add the extra data like description of news to it and when the persion clicks on the article they want to read make the ui visible and you can look for how to make a pop window to do so with js